# Append the "_commit_timestamp" Column to the Latest Data Version When Reading from a DeltaTable

Tags: scala, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have data in an delta lake WITHOUT a timestamp on each row to determine when that row was added/modified, but I only need rows that were created/modified after a specified date/time.

I want the latest version of the data from the delta lake but want to append "_commit_timestamp" from the change data feed to the dataframe read from the delta lake so that I can select only the data written after specified date/time, instead of the whole data set.

The change data feed returns all modifications to a row, i.e. insert/deletion/update so there can be multiple rows for the same row/data in each version.

Is there a way of getting just the latest version of the each row with the "_commit_timestamp" appended?

Comment: Have you looked at using the [`history`](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.scala#L125) method? This will give you the history of the Delta Lake as a DataFrame, which you could join onto.

Comment: Yes, but like I said the change data gives every operation that changed a row, so you could have 5 rows indicating read/write operations for a single row in the delta table, you'd then have to filter out a load of stuff to determine which is the timestamp to select or determine if the row was deleted etc. It just seemed complex and open to error. So I wanted to avoid doing it if I had to.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the delta table initially and implement merge operation later.

1. Altering will help to add the column to existing table
2. Merge the results and get updates of time stamp from new version.

   from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
   spark.read.format("delta").load('yourpath')
   .withColumn("Recovered", lit(''))
   .write
   .format("delta")
   .mode("overwrite")
   .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
   .save('yourpath')

While creating the table use the below method of using query

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (variables) TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

`delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true` helps to alter the data of the table after creation in delta table

```
set spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.enableChangeDataFeed = true;
```

for onetime property enabling, use the above command.

To use in python format, implement in below way.

```
# version as ints or longs
spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .option("endingVersion", 10) \
  .table("myDeltaTable")

# timestamps as formatted timestamp
spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingTimestamp", '2021-04-21 05:45:46') \
  .option("endingTimestamp", '2021-05-21 12:00:00') \
  .table("myDeltaTable")

# providing only the startingVersion/timestamp
spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .table("myDeltaTable")

# path based tables
spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingTimestamp", '2021-04-21 05:45:46') \
  .load("pathToMyDeltaTable")
```

for other language patterns kindly check the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-change-data-feed